# Is it possible to ensure at compile time that a given struct only exists at most once at any given point in time during the program lifecycle?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm wrapping an older C library which requires certain objects to only exist once at any given point in time during program execution.

Is it possible in Rust to guarantee such behavior for structs at compile time?

Or should I look into, how to create singletons and maybe pass an `Arc<MyWrapperStruct>` around?

I've looked into [`std::sync::Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html), but this looks like a tool to create something like a singleton or to ensure something happens at most once during the application lifetime.

It's totally fine for `MyWrapperStruct` to be instantiated multiple times, but the compiler should ensure `MyWrapperStruct` never exists concurrently (different threads) or in the same scope, somehow twice.

Subsequent instantiations of `MyWrapperStruct` are legal, as long the previous instances have been dropped and gone out of scope.

**Example**

```rust
pub struct MyWrapperStruct<'base> {
    pub base: &'base mut libc::c_void,
}

impl<'base> MyWrapperStruct<'base> {
    pub fn new(logfile: &str) -> MyWrapperStruct<'base> {
        let string = CString::new(logfile).unwrap();
        let mut base: &mut libc::c_void;
        unsafe {
            base = &mut *ptr::null_mut();

            // c-call here
            call_to_c_lib(&mut base, string.as_ptr());
        }
        MyWrapperStruct { base }
    }
}

fn should_not_compile() {
    MyWrapperStruct::new("log1.txt");
    MyWrapperStruct::new("log2.txt");
}

fn should_compile() {
    {
        MyWrapperStruct::new("log1.txt");
    }

    {
        MyWrapperStruct::new("log2.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: "It's totally fine for MyWrapperStruct to be instantiated multiple times, but the compiler should ensure MyWrapperStruct never exists concurrently (different threads)" How would the compiler check at compile time something that seems so dynamic?

Comment: @mcarton Yes. Maybe the answer to that "different threads" requirement is, Rust-compiler can't do that and I should look into, how to create a singleton of that struct and pass an Arc around, or something like that. Maybe I should use a different approach to wrap that C-lib safely. Hence the question ;)

Comment: I'd agree with mccarton, this is a very dynamic behaviour, compiler can't help and it it likely requires some sort of global lock (using `lazy_static!` or `once_cell`) held by the structure for its lifetime, and the ctor would need to be failible (otherwise you'll deadlock when trying to create a struct while one is alive).

Comment: Even using the lock as a token wouldn't help here, because locking a mutex only requires a ref', of which you can have multiple, and the borrow checker can't help you with mutable statics (they're unsafe by defintion). An alternative would be to create a "token" at the start of the program and thread it around, with the initialiser requiring ownership of the token and deinitialisation relinquishing the token (could use a mutable ref' instead of ownership, advantage is you couldn't "lose" the token, drawback's moving your struct would be way more complicated)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm going to rethink my implementation and requirements.

Comment: `&mut *ptr::null_mut()` is instant UB. It's very unlikely that a reference with lifetime is what you want for `base`. If `MyWrapperStruct` is supposed to represent ownership of the underlying C type, it should just contain a `*mut c_void` or possibly `NonNull<c_void>`and not have a lifetime parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this at compile time, however at runtime you can do this with a relatively straightforward atomic tracker.

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

static INSTANCE_EXISTS: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

pub struct MyStruct {}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn try_new() -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        if !INSTANCE_EXISTS.compare_and_swap(false, true, Ordering::SeqCst) {
            // Placeholder for C-side create object code
            Ok(MyStruct {})
        } else {
            Err("Instance of MyStruct currently exists")
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for MyStruct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // C-side destroy object code here

        INSTANCE_EXISTS.store(false, Ordering::Release);
    }
}
```

Note that if creation of `MyStruct` can fail, you'll need to do some extra bookkeeping to either undo the lock or poison it (i.e. signal to the program there's a catastrophic failure and no new `MyStruct` can be created).

As a slight aside to address your *specific* problem, holding a unique pointer to a C-side value is ownership, not a reference. It's basically just a `Box`. You don't want a lifetime or reference there, you want to directly hold the raw pointer, likely as a [`NonNull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html).

Comment: Note: I'm not 100% confident in my `Ordering` values because I only use raw atomics rarely, so if anyone sees any issue there please do an edit!

Comment: Thanks for your elaborative answer, example and hints how to treat my c-side value!